# How to use OpenFramework Responsive Grid Views?

Tags: views

For Drupal 7, the Bootstrap-based theme, OpenFramework, comes with css classes for Responsive Grid Views, such as "views-grid-four", but where/how are they used? Does the class name go into the Views administration somewhere, or in a css file?